# Can't get JQuery to work in MVC3 application at ALL?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This is driving me crazy, at the moment I can't get what seems a very simple piece of JQuery to work in my asp.net MVC3 application. I'm just starting to learn JQuery, I have created a new MVC 3 internet application and have added the following JQuery code to the top of index.cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready()(function() {
    $("#box").hide();
  });
</script>
```

I have also added the following html to the index.cshtml page:

```
<div id="box">
  blah
</div>
```

But when I load the page the div is not hidden, when I try debugging using firebug it seems like my script isn't even called. I've looked at god know how many tutorials tonight and I can't see what I'm missing, I'm sure it will be something simple. If anyone could spare some time to point it out it would be very much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error. The anonymous function is an argument to the ready method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#box").hide();
});
```

You can also use the ready handler shorcut if you'd like.

```
$(function() {
  $("#box").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is broken at the document ready, here is a fixed version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#box").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: (like rfvgyhn said, you pass the entire function to the ready() method, it might help to look at it this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
                    function()
                    {
                        $("#box").hide();
                    }
                    );
</script>
```